# Set class on asp.net input textbox automatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

If I use:

```
<%: Html.EditorForModel() %>
```

The texboxes get generated like this:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="Email" id="Email" class="text-box single-line">
```

ps. this method does not even do the validation.

If I use:

```
<%:Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Email)%>
```

Then the textbox gets generated without a class. How do I attach a class to all `Html.TextBoxFor()` just like what the above `Html.EditorForModel()` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John Hartsock is completely right - that's how you do it. However, if you want the class to be applied to all your textboxes, you could make your life (well) a little bit easier with a custom extension method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    return System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(
        helper, 
        expression, 
        new { @class = "text-box" });
}
```

It behaves just like the ordinary textbox helper, but with the added class:

```
<%: Html.MyTextBoxFor(m => m.Email) %>
```

Comment: No way to override the old TextBoxFor?

Comment: Well, I guess you could remove the <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" /> from your Web.config, but then a great number of useful extensions would need to be either imported on a per-page basis or used as the static methods they are. I think it would be much easier to just make a habit of using your own TextBoxFor implementation. Plus it's intuitive for other developers that might join your team later on.

Answer (score 1):

Like this...here is a reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions_methods.aspx

```
<%:Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Email, new { @class="yourclassnamehere" })%>
```

Comment: Someone thought you had misunderstood the question, when in fact you had it right and they had it wrong.

Comment: I know that one, is there a way to set this once/globally rather than on each textbox? ps. I didn't vote down.